# Autload with composer from a file with classmaps

Tags: php, composer-php, pear, autoload

In my project I use ezc components from PEAR. I want to move all dependency to composer so for it I've found https://github.com/lortnus/ezc. It's great, but I have a one problem - autoloading. There is an autoload folder with classmaps, but I don't have any clue how I can make composer's autoload to use them. Any idea how to do it?

**EDIT**

I've found two possible ways how to autoload these classes:
- fork lortnus/etc and add autoload in composer.json
- add autoload in composer.json in my project

Setting a classmap autoloader for all ezc classes will produce a huge autoload_classmap file. I'm not sure, but it can hit a performance a bit. Because of that I take a second approach and it looks like this:

```
"classmap": [
    "vendor/lortnus/ezc/Base/src",
    "vendor/lortnus/ezc/Mail/src"
]
```

and instead of creating a classmap for whole ez Components I end up of with a classmap with classes that I need. I don't like setting path to vendor folder, but think that's the best possibility here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do want to go through the hassle (or probably not) of upgrading, the current officially release packages of those "ezComponents" you are using are hosted [at Github under their newer name "Zeta Components"](https://github.com/zetacomponents).

The mail component in particular can be loaded with Composer via their name ["zetacomponents/mail"](https://packagist.org/packages/zetacomponents/mail). Autoloading is included. They still seem to do some maintenance, because after the 2009 release of version "1.7" there is already a 2014 release of "1.8 beta"

I cannot evaluate the amount of work required to upgrade your use of the older version to the newer one, but with only the mail component involved, this probably is a work worth doing.